# Rejex for markdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, python-markdown

Need to convert this text to two groups

I have added one markdown

```
CUSTOM_CLS_RE = r"[!]{2}(?P<class>[^!]+)[|](?P<text>[^!]+)[!]{2}"
```

Which convert

```
I love !!text-alert|spam!!
```

TO

```
2 groups I love and spam
```

similar
I need to make another regex here to change

```
!---
 Content HERE
---!{text-align:right;}
```

this to 2 groups,

```
Content HERE and text-align:right
```

My current rejex pattern is `r"[-]{3}(?P<class>[^[-]{3}]+)[!{](?P<text>[^;}]+)"` its not working